# Change The Initials of Comments made in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

How to Change The Initials of Comments made in Microsoft Word?

I tried the following and it is only changing the new comments and existing comments are unable to be changed.

Options --> Initial Name --> Changed --> Saved --> Restart Docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referred this link https://superuser.com/questions/208153/renaming-the-initials-in-word-comments and used the macro option and code provided. It worked :)

```
Sub ChangeInitialsAndAuthor()
    For Each MyComment In ActiveDocument.Comments
        If MyComment.Initial = "old" Then MyComment.Initial = "new"
    Next
End Sub
```

#### How to use the macro

- Open your Word file and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- Insert a new module and copy & paste the code above
- Change `old` to your old initials and `new` to your new initials
- Run the macro with <kbd>F5</kbd> from the editor or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> from word

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. You have do it manually.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/change-the-author-name-for-review-comments-HA010036415.aspx

Comment: I tried it. It did not work :(